# How to set correct permissions for OwnCloud user on RPi3?

Tags: pi-3b+, owncloud

I'm setting my RPi3 to serve OwnCloud and I've got external drive for the data. My issue is that when selecting location where my data folder is into the set-up page it gives me: `error can't create or write into the data directory`

so I added `UUID=F307-C810 /media/pi/F307-C810 auto nofail,uid=33,gid=33,umask=0027,dmask=0$` into `/etc/fstab` file which sets ownership of the drive on every boot. 33 is id of the OwnCloud user and F307-C810 being the drive id.

I also ran `sudo chmod -R 775 /media/pi/F307-C810` which should give sufficient permissions for my use case.

Yet I get the error. What else I can try ?

Comment: What format is the disk?  You could try checking the ownership of the mount point and directories below that and the ownership of the objects of the drive.

Comment: Other people who have given me input said it's best to use Linux filesystem (ext4). I reformatted the drive to ext4 but the error didn't go away.

Comment: Yes, when I reboot RPi and check the ownership / permissions for the drive and directories and files within. They get the correct ownership on every boot.